# Linq C#, less performance with join vs multiple lookups

Tags: c#, performance, linq, join

I have an older version of code that was doing multiple lookup. I needed some additional fields so instead i rewrote it to do a couple joins and return everything i needed at once. I imagined this would have better performance, but when testing with a stopwatch this was not the case and quite slower. Am i inadvertently doing something wrong with my query?

### Old Code

```
// ===============================old
            var watchOld = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var def = context.FDataMLBPlayers.Where(d => d.Status.Trim().ToLower().Equals("active") && d.Position.Trim().ToLower().Equals(position.ToLower())).OrderBy(d => d.Team);
            foreach (var dd in def)
            {
                bool addPlayer = false;
                foreach (var tm in teams)
                {
                    if (tm.Trim().Equals(dd.Team.Trim()))
                    {
                        addPlayer = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!addPlayer) continue;
                Player player = new Player();
                player.Name = dd.FirstName.Trim() + " " + dd.LastName.Trim();
                player.LastName = dd.LastName.Trim();
                player.Number = dd.Jersey.HasValue ? dd.Jersey.Value : 0;
                player.PlayerID = dd.PlayerID;
                player.Points = 0;
                player.Position = (dd.Position == null) ? "" : dd.Position.Trim();
                player.Score = 0;
                player.Status = "Active";//DOROC dd.CurrentStatus;
                player.Team = dd.Team.Trim();
                htop ht = GetOpposingTeam(dd.Team.Trim()); //another lookup
                player.OpposingTeam = ht.OpposingTeam;
                player.PhotoUrl = dd.PhotoUrl.Trim();
                player.IsHomeTeam = ht.IsHomeTeam;
                if (dd.Position != null)
                {
                    list.Add(player);
                }
            }
            watchOld.Stop();
            var oldTime = watchOld.ElapsedMilliseconds; // 227 ms
```

### New Code

```
// ========================================== new
            var watchNew = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var def2 = (from p in context.FDataMLBPlayers
                       join g in context.FDataMLBPlayerGames on p.PlayerID equals g.PlayerID
                       join t in context.FDataMLBTeams on g.OpponentID equals t.TeamID
                       where p.Status.Trim().ToLower().Equals("active")
                       && p.Position.Trim().ToLower().Equals(position.ToLower()) 
                       && teams.Contains(p.Team)
                       group new { p, g, t }
                       by new { p.PlayerID } into pgt
                       let fod = pgt.FirstOrDefault()
                       select new Player
                       {
                           DateTime = fod.g.DateTime.Value,
                           IsHomeTeam = fod.g.HomeOrAway.ToLower().Equals("home") ? true : false,
                           LastName = fod.p.LastName,
                           Name = fod.p.FirstName.Trim() + " " + fod.p.LastName.Trim(),
                           Number = fod.p.Jersey.HasValue ? fod.p.Jersey.Value : 0,
                           OpposingTeam = fod.t.Name,
                           PhotoUrl = fod.p.PhotoUrl,
                           PlayerID = fod.p.PlayerID,
                           Points = 0,
                           Position = fod.p.Position,
                           Score = 0,                              
                           Started = fod.g.Started.Value.Equals(1) ? true : false, 
                           Status = fod.p.Status, 
                           Team = fod.p.Team,       
                        }
                ).ToList();       
            list = def2;
            watchNew.Stop();
            var newTime = watchNew.ElapsedMilliseconds; // 399 ms
```

---

Comment: Log the SQL that gets generated between the two queries. See what result set is generated against the database.

Comment: Also, did you try running the query multiple times? EntityFramework in particular is slow on first query and then faster on subsequent runs of the same query.

Comment: How many items are returned?

Comment: 41 Items returned. I did try and run a few more times and noticed fluctuations and they are much closer now and only 50 or so ms apart, but generally the old code seems to be winning most tries. 

I wanted to examine the SQL it generates just wasn't sure how.

Comment: The first query doesn't seem to retrieve the same data, in particular the `Game` related information. Also you'd better use navigation properties since it's not quite clear what's the cardinality of the joins, hence the group by operator could be redundant.

Comment: Assuming the 50 ms difference is significant, this could just be evidence that Linq to entity provider has done a better job translating association to sql than it does translating joins. How long does the query run overall by the way?